# SAFARI EXTENSION : Send messages from popup to content script

Tags: google-chrome-extension, safari-extension, chrome-extension-manifest-v3

I am working on a project that creates an extension. First I coded chrome-extension. Then using safari converter, I return to safari extension.
In popup, I am trying to inject script as,

```
const buttonList = document.querySelectorAll(".app-button-inbox")
                for (let index = 0; index < buttonList.length; index++) {
                    buttonList[index].addEventListener("click", async () => {
                        try {
                            console.log('kac kez', index, inboxTabId)
                            await chrome.scripting.executeScript({
                                target: { tabId: inboxTabId, allFrames: true}
                                , files: ['contentScript.js']
                            }, () => {
                                chrome.runtime.sendMessage({message: 'hello'})
                            })
                        } catch (error) {
                            console.log('buradan', error)
                        }
                    })
                }
```

I want to access a variable using message passing and in my content script file I use runtime onMessage:

```
console.log('son')
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(function(message, sender, sendResponse) {
    console.log(message, sender, sendResponse)
});
```

However my message not seems correctly. It seems like this :

[image]

How can I fix it? why message seems anormal ?

Comment: Use chrome.tabs.sendMessage (not runtime) with a tab id, see the documentation for more info.

Comment: Any update for Safari extension?